# Handlebars block expression do not work

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Yesterday I decided to learn Handlebars, watched a couple of tutorials and so on. But I encountered some weird behavior w/ my code.

1)I have my json data:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "price": 488.98,
      "available": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "price": 520.89,
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

2) My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Handlebars</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="divToPopulate">
      <!-- population w/ data -->
    </div>

    <script id="hdtemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each products}}

        {{#toUpper name}}
        {{/toUpper}}

        {{#toStrong}}
          <h4>{{price}}</h4>
        {{/toStrong}}

        {{#if available}}
          <p>{{available}}</p>
          {{else}}<p>Out of stock</p>
        {{/if}}

      {{/each}}
    </script>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.8/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3) And my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  const inittemp = $('#hdtemp').html();
  const template = Handlebars.compile(inittemp);

  Handlebars.registerHelper("toUpper",(property)=>{
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`<h2>${property.toUpperCase()}</h2>`);
  });

  Handlebars.registerHelper("toStrong", (options)=>{
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`<p><strong>${options.fn(this)}</strong></p>`);
  });

  $.ajax("products.json").done((data)=>{
    $('#divToPopulate').html(template(data));
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And for some reason when I render the page my "toStrong" helper block expression does not work.

```
{{#toStrong}}
              <h4>{{price}}</h4>
            {{/toStrong}}
```

The one before that ("toUpper") works just fine, but as soon as I use options.fn(this) instead of {{price}} I get black element. W/ ctrl+shift+i, I have no errors in the console, everything else seems to be working just fine. 
Any idea what seems to be wrong? Thank you!

P.S: yesterday I even encountered the weirdest thing and again with options.fn
I had an element h4 and used block expr. to generate {{place}} and there was the address of my localhost, like: `<h4>127.0.0.1:8080</h4>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toStrong` helper is almost correct. The thing that bit you is the use of [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

When using arrow function in a block helper, doing: `option.fn(this)` isn't what you expect, that `this` isn't the current handlebars context, it is `document` in your case.
So what you are doing is passing the document as a new context. That's why `{{price}}` inside the block helper isn't showing anything. But if you do {{../price}} it would print the correct value.

**You should avoid using arrow functions when registering handlebars helpers.** Unless you are aware of the consequences.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("toUpper", function(property){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`<h2>${property.toUpperCase()}</h2>`);
```

});

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("toStrong", function(options){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`<p><strong>${options.fn(this)}</strong></p>`);
  });
```

You can also change the way you use toUpper helper, since it isn't a block helper.

```
{{{toUpper name}}} <!-- see below -->
```

or

```
{{toUpper name}} <!-- html will be escaped in your case -->
```

instead of

```
{{#toUpper name}}{{/toUpper}}
```

**triple-stash**

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{

```js
var data = {
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "price": 488.98,
      "available": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "price": 520.89,
      "available": false
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  const inittemp = $('#hdtemp').html();
  const template = Handlebars.compile(inittemp);

  Handlebars.registerHelper("toUpper",function(property){
    return `<h2>${property.toUpperCase()}</h2>`;
  });

   Handlebars.registerHelper("toStrong", function(options){

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`<p><strong>${options.fn(this)}</strong></p>`);
  });

  
    console.log(template(data));
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Handlebars</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="divToPopulate">
      <!-- population w/ data -->
    </div>

    <script id="hdtemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each products}}

        {{{toUpper name}}}

        {{#toStrong}}
          <h4>{{price}}</h4>
        {{/toStrong}}

        {{#if available}}
          <p>{{available}}</p>
          {{else}}<p>Out of stock</p>
        {{/if}}

      {{/each}}
    </script>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.8/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have guessed that es6 syntax was the problem. I've been there before. Had the same problem with arrow functions when learnt Angular. Thank again!